# I got Session proposal trying to log in to Opensea: Events: chainChanged, accountsChanged

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, accounts, opensea, wallet-transfer

Would really appreciate your help. Is that a scam? I cannot log in without resolving the wallet Session proposal. So far i have denied request several times. What happens is i Approve?

NetworkEthereum
Methodseth_sendTransaction, eth_signTypedData_v4, personal_sign